# How to stream video from my App Camera to RTMP server directly?

Tags: ios, swift, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api, facebook-live-api

I want to stream video from iOS Camera to RTMP server directly 
**For Example:** I want to stream live video to facebook from my application camera

I have stream url but how to use it???

Third Party library links are welcome

**I want to use it for Facebook live API and youtube live API**

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Yes I tried but failed in all way...

Comment: Show the code, let us know what exactly is not working, we need something to work with

Comment: I tried HaishinKit https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift

Comment: did you find anything about facebook live stream I am stuck in this too

Comment: No @AnujShrestha